# read files directly VS getent

Tags: nsswitch, getent

In various shell scripts I often see two approaches for getting information from databases supported by *Name Service Switch* libraries like `/etc/group`, `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/services`. One is `getent` utility and other is `grep` or some other text processing tool. For example:

```
root@fw-test:~# getent passwd root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
root@fw-test:~# 


root@fw-test:~# grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
root@fw-test:~#
```

..or:

```
root@fw-test:~# getent hosts www.blah.com
189.113.174.199 www.blah.com
root@fw-test:~# 

root@fw-test:~# host www.blah.com
www.blah.com has address 189.113.174.199
root@fw-test:~#
```

Which of those two approaches above should be used in scripts? I mean is one of the solutions more elegant or standard than the other?

Comment: At the command line on a nearly fresh install of Fedora Silverblue 37, `cat /etc/passwd` shows one entry (me) while `getent passwd` shows maybe 30 users.  Same with getent group.  Probably this means the command line I'm using is actually running in a container?  That would fit with the Silverblue theme.  `getent` must be more globally aware (such as querying the host os?) while `/etc/passwd` seems to be more local (to the container?).  If you're picking a uid for running other containers, getent is what you need to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lot of this will come down to factors stemming from the specific environment you're in, but I prefer the `getent` method because it looks up external users as well as local users. Specifically, it will look up the LDAP users in my environment from the LDAP server, whereas a `cat /etc/passwd` or similar has no idea my LDAP server even exists, much less has valid users on it. If all your users are always local, `getent` doesn't really buy you much aside from "no need to rewrite if we add an LDAP server in 10 years".

Answer (score 6):

The `getent` approach would be more compatible and preferable. Those files (/etc/group, /etc/hosts, /etc/services, /etc/passwd, ...) are not always in `/etc` they could also be, depending on the operating system you're on, in other places. `getent` would anyway find the entries (if it's on the system).

Also as @John stated, `getent` searches trough all configured nsswitch databases. Even if you have (multiple) external sources connected, where your users are authenticated with or name resolutions via DNS-servers and so on. `getent` therefore is slower, because every lookup must go trough all databases.