# How to get HOME, given USER?

Tags: bash, shell-script, users

I have an `USER` variable in my script, and I want to see his `HOME` path based on the `USER` variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the `$USER` the name of the user that runs the script, or is it an arbitrary username?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There is a utility which will lookup user information regardless of whether that information is stored in local files such as `/etc/passwd` or in LDAP or some other method. It's called `getent`.

In order to get user information out of it, you run `getent passwd $USER`. You'll get a line back that looks like:

```
[jenny@sameen ~]$ getent passwd jenny
jenny:*:1001:1001:Jenny Dybedahl:/home/jenny:/usr/local/bin/bash
```

Now you can simply cut out the home dir from it, e.g. by using cut, like so:

```
[jenny@sameen ~]$ getent passwd jenny | cut -d: -f6
/home/jenny
```

Comment: getent is the better answer, specially with remote user. in simpler systems ~user should be enough. Modded you up.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro you can't use `~foo` with variables in `bash`. Not directly, anyway.

Comment: @muru - that's true - and is spec'd behavior. the `~` does seem to tab-expand, though, and another spec'd behavior of *the tilde-prefix shall be replaced by a pathname of the initial working directory associated with the login name obtained using the `getpwnam()` function* and so probably that lookup is pretty good. i dont like tab-expansions, though - i like to type tabs.

Comment: Note that this only gets you the *initial* value of $HOME; the user's login scripts are perfectly entitled to change it to something else.  This is an unusual thing to do, but I can think of situations where it would be sensible, e.g. choosing between a local and an NFS-mounted homedir.

Comment: Should one be prepared for a line `jenny:*:1001:1001:Jenny Dy\:bedahl:/home/jen\:ny:/usr/local/bin/bash` or are colons really forbidden in both full name and home dir?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Colons are forbidden precisely because they have been used to separate fields.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `eval` to get someone's home directory.

```
eval echo "~$USER"
```

At least for local users this works for sure. I don't know if remote users like LDAP are handled with `eval`.

Comment: No need for eval there. Be careful with your english.

Comment: @nwk an `eval` is needed. Bash doesn't process `~foo` after variable expansion.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, however this only gets the directory of the *current* user, not of other users. I think LDAP users are not handled, though I can be wrong.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It will work fine with LDAP, just use whatever variable contains your LDAP user's username instead of `USER`.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro: I agree, $USER is a bad choice. It works with a self assigned variable.

Comment: Don't use this without verifying that `$USER` expands to *just* a single string of alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 4):

The usual place is `/home/$USER`, but that does not have to be universal.
The definitive place to search for such information is inside the file `/etc/passwd`.

That file is world readable (anyone could read it), so any user has access to its contents.
If the $USER exists in the file, the entry previous to last is the user HOME directory.

This will select the entry and print the HOME directory:

```
awk -v FS=':' -v user="$USER" '($1==user) {print $6}' "/etc/passwd"
```

For more complex (remote) systems, getent is the usual command to get users information from the NSS (Name Service Switch libraries) system.

A command of

```
getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d : -f 6
```

Will provide equivalent information (if available).

Comment: you have ~user for that, and your solution does not contemplate users in more complex systems, like user coming from LDAP where you have to use getent.

Answer (score 3):

If the user doesn't exist, `getent` will return an error.

Here's a small shell function that doesn't ignore the exit code of `getent`:

```
get_home() {
  local result; result="$(getent passwd "$1")" || return
  echo $result | cut -d : -f 6
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
da_home="$(get_home missing_user)" || {
  echo 'User does NOT exist!'; exit 1
}

# Now do something with $da_home
echo "Home directory is: '$da_home'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in as root, if you know `USER`'s password, or if the `USER` has no password, the following is yet another option:

```bash
    su -c 'echo ~' ${USER}
```

Under standard `su` behavior, if `USER` is undefined or empty, then `su` will attempt to run the command as root.

If the value of `USER` is not a valid user name, then an appropriate error will be raised: `su: user <user> does not exist`.

There are already plenty of good answers here but this may still help someone.

Comment: This isn't secure, depending on system config. It runs a process (the shell running echo) as that user, so the user could (for example) ptrace the shell and give you arbitrary output. It's also running in the user's setup, so it's possible that the users shell config files are run (which could also give arbitrary outputs). Or environment loads via pam. Etc. Or just do something as simple as send it a SIGSTOP to make it take forever, effectively DOS attacking your script.

Answer (score 1):

`getent` is not reliable...

`getent` will not work as expected for usernames consisting of all numerics.

Consider username of '0029', getent will return system rpc (in my case, rpc may have a different uid on your system) user details and not username 0029 details.

`chown` and a few other system commands will also have issues...
see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/310363

Also see getent man page.

`/etc/passwd` is readable by all, so try

```
'awk -F':' -v U=$USER '$1==U {print $6}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Link gives "access denied".

Comment: @kikenchitai your link has nothing to do with `chmod` and `getent`, could you check whether it’s actually the link you wanted to use?

Comment: I'm also getting "access denied" for the Red Hat page. However, I verified -- @kikenchitai is right (at least in RHEL 9). Manpages are obscure but mention only non-numeric keys are passed to `getpwnam(3)`. As an alternative solution, use `getent passwd | grep '^username:'` (from https://stackoverflow.com/q/35909572/1941654). Either way, we're just getting the passwd database and parsing for the home path.

Answer (score 1):

Several reasonable solutions are already posted, but all have issues. For example:

- `getent passwd "${MY_USER}" | cut -d: -f6`: Will fail for numeric usernames, as pointed out by @kikenchitai. `getent passwd "<value>"` assumes UIDs when given numeric values.
- `eval echo "~${MY_USER}"`: `eval` is vulnerable to several security concerns. Additionally, this will fail for usernames with spaces or other interpreted characters.
- `awk -v FS=':' -v user="${MY_USER}" '($1==user) {print $6}' "/etc/passwd"`: `/etc/passwd` does not provide a complete representation of users, hence the need for `getent`. See [read files directly VS getent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196829/read-files-directly-vs-getent).

  *Note: See discussion on using `getent passwd` here instead of `/etc/passwd` in comments. In short, one critical caveat of `getent passwd` is that remote users are often not bulk-listable. `getent passwd` only lists local users in many cases, whereas `getent passwd <UID>` also queries remote user databases.*
- `su -c 'echo ~' "${MY_USER}"`: Requires elevated access, among other security concerns (as mentioned by @derobert).
- `getent passwd | grep "^${MY_USER}:"`: Subject to regex injection. Also subject to `getent passwd` only querying the local user database in many cases.

This is the most reliable solution I've seen so far:

```
getent passwd "$(id -u "${MY_USER}")" | cut -d: -f6
```

Explanation:

- `id -u "${MY_USER}"`: Get the user's UID. This should reliably work with local and non-local users (e.g., LDAP users via SSSD).
- `getent passwd "<UID>"`: Get passwd data for the given UID. This will search all user databases via Name Service Switch (not just `/etc/passwd`).
- `cut -d: -f6`: Pull the home directory field. This should be consistent across the majority of systems. Most (all?) distributions both assign the sixth field to the home directory and explicitly reserve colons as delimiters without escaping.

Comment: The awk one is trivially fixable - just pipe getent to it instead.

Comment: Note too that `getent passwd` isn’t usable everywhere — many directory-based setups prevent listing all the users, in which case `getent passwd` only shows locally-defined users.

Comment: @muru trivially fixable with the caveat just above (and if that’s fixed by giving the user name on the command line, the caveat mentioned in the first bullet point).

Comment: Thanks for the discussion @muru and @stephen-kitt -- added some commentary to explain this. I see the same behavior on my hosts, where `getent passwd` with no additional parameters only lists local users.